# Can I interpolate my large (X,Y,Z) dataset to get data for different temperatures than I collected?

Tags: matlab

I have 4 columns of test data (Temp, X, Y, Z). I want to create slices  of data (X,Y,Z) for temperatures not collected (0, 40, 100). Each temperature would create a 3d dataset that I would want to graph as a surface. My data does not have the exact temperatures so how can I interpolate the data to get the data I am after?

My data is for each temp (-20, 60, 120, 160), X varied from 0 to 1 and Y varied from 1000 to 10000 and Z was measured. I would like to know how I can create the X, Y and Z data for different temperatures with X and Y varying the same way.

Also for each temperature, X and Y do not vary the same. They are not grided, One test run X might be 0.05, 0.34, 0.68 etc... whereas the next time it might be 0.02, 0.28, 0.57 etc...

I have tried interpn and griddatan but have not been successful. I am fairly new to Matlab which is probably my problem.

I have tried something like...

```
data = [X Y Z];
interp_data = interp1(Temp, data, -20, 'linear');
```

Comment: Please, show us how you tried `interpn` and `griddata` so we can help you fix that code.

Comment: So you have a surface for each temperature, and you want to find corresponding surfaces for intermediate temperatures? You can do this is the XYZT hyper-volume is sampled sufficiently densely. If not, then you have aliasing, and interpolation will give nonsense. How smooth is your data compared to the sampling density?

Comment: I used a LHS technique to create the inputs for my test model that created the data. I have 151 test points that is to create a surface that should be within 95% accuracy within the bounds of my input parameters.